# C# | Как подправить алгоритм?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, пароль, .net-5

Я захотел написать свой генератор пароля на **C#**, который спрашивал: длину пароля, сколько спец. символов, сколько чисел. Конечно, всё было без проблем, кроме одной. Если я ставил, например, длину 7, спец. символов 2, чисел 2, то он длину сделал правильно, кол-во чисел правильно, но вот только спец. символ только один. Он сгенерировал 3, 4 индекс (буквы), но не оставшийся спец. символ. Так вот. Как мне сделать чтобы все условия были бы выполнены?
Мой код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using static System.Console;

var random = new Random();

var userPasswordData = ReadLine()?.Split(' ');
var lengthRequired = int.Parse(userPasswordData?[0] ?? "7");
var specialSymbolsRequired = int.Parse(userPasswordData?[1] ?? "2");
var numbersRequired = int.Parse(userPasswordData?[2] ?? "2");

var charactersList = new List<string>
{
    "0123456789",
    "!@#$%&*",
    // ReSharper disable once StringLiteralTypo
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
    // ReSharper disable once StringLiteralTypo
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
};
var generatedPasswordData = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    {"SpecialSymbols", 0},
    {"Numbers", 0}
};
var generatedPassword = "";

for (var i = 1; i <= lengthRequired; i++)
{
    var rowIndex = 0;
    var columnIndex = 0;
    
    // If it's first letter of generation password.
    if (i == 1)
    {
        rowIndex = random.Next(2, charactersList.Count);
        columnIndex = random.Next(0, charactersList[rowIndex].Length);

        generatedPassword += charactersList[rowIndex][columnIndex];
        continue;
    }
    
    do
    {
        rowIndex = random.Next(0, charactersList.Count);

        // If row at numbers
        if (rowIndex == 0)
        {
            if (generatedPasswordData["Numbers"] < numbersRequired)
            {
                columnIndex = random.Next(0, charactersList[rowIndex].Length);

                generatedPassword += charactersList[rowIndex][columnIndex];
                generatedPasswordData["Numbers"] += 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        // If row at Special Symbols
        else if (rowIndex == 1)
        {
            if (generatedPasswordData["SpecialSymbols"] < specialSymbolsRequired)
            {
                columnIndex = random.Next(0, charactersList[rowIndex].Length);

                generatedPassword += charactersList[rowIndex][columnIndex];
                generatedPasswordData["SpecialSymbols"] += 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        // If row at letters.
        else
        {
            columnIndex = random.Next(0, charactersList[rowIndex].Length);

            generatedPassword += charactersList[rowIndex][columnIndex];
            break;
        }
    } while (true);
    
    
}
WriteLine(generatedPassword);
```

Comment: У Вас и цифр не всегда две. В вашем алгоритме нет контроля за количеством спецсимволов или цифр, это в воле случайности.

Comment: Вы слишком прямо подошли к задаче. Возьмите просто и сгенерируйте сначала первый символ - букву, затем `specialSymbolsRequired`-специальных символов, `numbersRequired`-цифр и `lengthRequired - specialSymbolsRequired - numbersRequired - 1` букв. Сложите все это в одну строку, перетасуйте ее символы и верните юзеру обратно.

Comment: @Andrei Khotko тасовать без первого символа надо. Просто уточняю.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в вашем алгоритме кроется в том, что вы не контролируете количество сгенерированных букв. Что вам нужно поменять в вашем алгоритме, чтобы все работало правильно?

1. Вычислить требуемое количество букв, которое должно содержать
   итоговая строка:

   ```
   var lettersRequired = lengthRequired - specialSymbolsRequired - numbersRequired - 1; // -1 учитывает первый символ пароля, который обязательно должен быть буквой
   ```
2. Добавить в словарь `generatedPasswordData` счетчик "Letters":

   ```
   var generatedPasswordData = new Dictionary<string, int>
   {
       {"SpecialSymbols", 0},
       {"Numbers", 0},
       {"Letters", 0}
   };
   ```
3. В месте, где вы генерируете буквы, добавьте аналогичное условие на
   ограничение количества сгенерированных букв:

   ```
   // If row at letters.
   else if (generatedPasswordData["Letters"] < lettersRequired)
   {
       columnIndex = random.Next(0, charactersList[rowIndex].Length);

       generatedPassword += charactersList[rowIndex][columnIndex];
       generatedPasswordData["Letters"]++;
       break;
   }
   ```

**P.S.** Я бы на вашем месте вынес код генерации символов в отдельный класс. Возможно, чуть позже дополню ответ с улучшениями вашего кода.

Comment: Решение с Вашим дополнением не обеспечивает контроль количества спецсимволов.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey можете показать/доказать, почему не обеспечивает?

Comment: Виноват, поспешил с выводом, решение рабочее. Правда холостые итерации в цикле смущают, но это не имеет большого значения.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey это да, лишние итерации здесь есть. Данный вариант - лишь ответ на вопрос автора `Как подправить алгоритм?` :)

Answer (score 0):

Лови

```
namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            var random = new Random();
            int gh = 0;
            int gy = 0;
            var userPasswordData = ReadLine()?.Split(' ');
            var lengthRequired = 7; //int.Parse(userPasswordData?[0] ?? "7");
            var specialSymbolsRequired = 5; //int.Parse(userPasswordData?[1] ?? "2");
            var numbersRequired = 2;// int.Parse(userPasswordData?[2] ?? "2");

            var charactersList = new List<string>
{
    "0123456789",
    "!@#$%&*",
    // ReSharper disable once StringLiteralTypo
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
    // ReSharper disable once StringLiteralTypo
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
};
            var generatedPasswordData = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    {"SpecialSymbols", 0},
    {"Numbers", 0}
};
            var generatedPassword = "";

            for (var i = 1; i <= lengthRequired; i++)
            {
                var rowIndex = 0;
                var columnIndex = 0;

                do
                {
                    rowIndex = random.Next(0, charactersList.Count);

                    // If row at numbers
                    if (rowIndex == 0)
                    {
                        if (generatedPasswordData["Numbers"] < numbersRequired)
                        {
                            gy++;
                            columnIndex = random.Next(0, charactersList[rowIndex].Length);

                            generatedPassword += charactersList[rowIndex][columnIndex];
                            generatedPasswordData["Numbers"] += 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    // If row at Special Symbols
                     if (rowIndex == 1)
                    {
                        if (generatedPasswordData["SpecialSymbols"] < specialSymbolsRequired)
                        {
                            gh++;
                            columnIndex = random.Next(0, charactersList[rowIndex].Length);
                            
                            generatedPassword += charactersList[rowIndex][columnIndex];
                            generatedPasswordData["SpecialSymbols"] += 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    // If row at letters.
                    else if (gh + gy == specialSymbolsRequired+numbersRequired)
                    {
                        columnIndex = random.Next(0, charactersList[rowIndex].Length);

                        generatedPassword += charactersList[rowIndex][columnIndex];
                        break;
                    }
                } while (true);


            }
            WriteLine(generatedPassword);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я предлагаю по другому подойти к решению.
Сначала создаём маску будущего пароля, которая соответствует нашим условиям. Эта маска содержит индексы на наборы символов.
Затем "перетасовываем" маску и в цикле вычисляем новые символы для пароля.

```
Random random = new Random();

var lengthRequired = 7;
var specialSymbolsRequired = 2;
var numbersRequired = 2;

var charactersList = new List<string>
{
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
    "0123456789",
    "!@#$%&*"
};

String mask = (new String('1', numbersRequired) + new String('2', specialSymbolsRequired)).PadRight(lengthRequired-1, '0');
String smask = '0' + new string(mask.ToCharArray().OrderBy(x => random.NextDouble()).ToArray());
            
String generatedPassword = "";

for (int i = 0; i < lengthRequired; i++)
{
    int rowIndex = smask[i] - 48;
    int columnIndex = random.Next(0, charactersList[rowIndex].Length);

    generatedPassword += charactersList[rowIndex][columnIndex];
}

Console.WriteLine(generatedPassword);
```

`smask` - это перетасованная маска. '0' в начале гарантирует, что первый символ будет буква.
Рекомендую найти более качественный shuffle-алгоритм.